# LaTeX editor that works seamlessly between iOS (iPadOS) and MacOS

Tags: editors, macos, ipad

I am planning to get an iPad Pro this Autumn and was looking into editor options.

What would be a good editor that can work smoothly between the iPad and MacBook? Something that allows me to switch devices without dealing with the hassle of moving files around different platforms.

I know that Overleaf would be an option, but I would like to consider some “Apps” as well.

Answer (score 3):

I have used two Apps, first [Texpad](https://www.texpad.com/ios) and then I changed to [TeX Writer](https://apps.texwriter.net), which is the one I continue using. 
Both store everything locally and on Dropbox, so you can work on your docs on the computer also.

I have only WiFi connection on the iPad, so I have to be a bit careful to have it sinchronized before continuing on another device, but conflicted copies are stored so you can resolve them.

I changed some years back because I did not like the keyboard of Texpad, the one of TeX Writer being much better, in my opinion. Braces, square brackets, $, %, etc. are all immediately available which is very comfortable. 
And you can make an index, which was not possible at that time in Texpad.

Also I had once a problem with synchronization on Texpad, but I expect they have solved those issues now.